# Trouble sending multiple attachments on emails, only able to send one file attachment

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, email-attachments

I have a working vb.net that sends a email with an attachment to the recipient with the data from the fields as well.  But I have 2 issues:

1. I cannot attach more than one file to the email even if I select more than one.
2. I would like to be able to see what I'm attaching so I could delete the attachment if necessary before submitting the details on the form.

Your help would be much appreciated, thanks.

I have a attachment button which you can browse for:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim openDLG As New OpenFileDialog

    openDLG.AddExtension = True
    openDLG.ReadOnlyChecked = True
    openDLG.Multiselect = True
    openDLG.Title = "Select the file(s) you want added to the message..."
    openDLG.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*"

    If openDLG.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        For Each item As String In openDLG.FileNames

            'Create a new System.NET.Mail.Attachment class instance for each file.
            attachToMsg = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(item)

        Next

        MsgBox("I have finished adding all of the selected files! You can do more if you want!")

    End If
```

Then I have a submit button that sends all the information including attachment(s) from the form:

```
 Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Using message As New MailMessage()

        message.From = (New MailAddress(TextBox3.Text.ToString()))
        message.[To].Add(New MailAddress("benjamin.boothe@experian.com"))
        message.Subject = "New commission query"




        message.Attachments.Add(attachToMsg)

        Dim MsgBody As String
        MsgBody = TextBox1.Text.ToString() & vbCr & _
                  TextBox2.Text.ToString() & vbCr & _
                  TextBox3.Text.ToString() & vbCr & _
                  ComboBox1.Text.ToString() & vbCr & _
                  ComboBox2.Text.ToString() & vbCr & _
                  ComboBox3.Text.ToString() & vbCr & _
                  ComboBox4.Text.ToString() & vbCr
        message.Body = MsgBody
        Dim client As New SmtpClient()
        client.Host = "mailhost"
        client.Send(message)

    End Using

    MessageBox.Show("Your request has been submitted!", "Congratulations!")
    'close form
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

jamman

Comment: Please provide some code, specifically where you add the attachments to the mail object.

Comment: If openDLG.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            For Each item As String In openDLG.FileNames
                attachToMsg = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(item) Then use the attach to the message:  message.Attachments.Add(attachToMsg)

Comment: Edit your post and put the code there ;) One suggestion: `attachMsg` is set to a new Mail.Attachment each time, so I suspect your email only contains the last selected file?

Comment: Yes John, exactly that.

Comment: Okay, the solution is to attach the `attachMsg` to the email every time you create it from a new file. In other words, attach the attachments inside your `For Each` loop.

Comment: I basically added the  `message.Attachments.Add(attachToMsg)`statement within the `For Each` loop.  Is that what you meant?  If so, that didn't work. Plus I updated the post to give you clearer picture as to what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining your attachment object once and assigning each file to the same attachment object. You should define your attachment as a `List(Of Attachement)`.

So instead of

`Private attachToMsg As System.Net.Mail.Attachment`

do this:

`Private attachmentList As List(Of System.Net.Mail.Attachment)`

Then when user user selects the files:

```
attachmentList = New List(Of System.Net.Mail.Attachment)
If openDLG.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    For Each item As String In openDLG.FileNames
        'Create a new System.NET.Mail.Attachment class instance for each file.
        attachmentList.add(New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(item))
    Next
    MsgBox("I have finished adding all of the selected files! You can do more if you want!")
End If
```

Now in your sending code add each attachment:

```
If Not attachmentList Is Nothing Then
    For Each attachment As System.Net.Mail.Attachment In attachmentList 
        message.Attachments.Add(attachment)
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Matt Wilko, thank you very much. I can now send multiple attachments on one email. You've been very helpful.

Comment: Any suggestions about the second question I asked originally??